# I need to use reference variable or not? (LinkedList)

Tags: java

I have a situation that I need to fill an object array.

This is my code:

```
final class ObjectClass
{
    List<ObjectClass> array;
    private int data;

    ObjectClass(int data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void fillArray() {
        array = new LinkedList<>();
        for(int i = 0;i < array.size();i++)
        {
            data++;
            array.add(new ObjectClass(data));
        }

    }
}
```

And i am getting no result with this. What is wrong with that? 
Is it valid to add like this: `array.add(new ObjectClass(data))` ?

*There is no point about results and logic in this situation. I just want to make the ObjectClass's array with different data values.*  I saw, someone used a reference variable and stored it in an array,  but is it valid to make it without it by creating only object?

Add a print method:

```
    public void display() {
    for(ObjectClass e : array) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean you are getting "no results"? What have you tried? What _specifically_ happened?

Comment: I am trying to make an ObjectClass array and print it's objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you call `fillArray`, you are destroying the data (however it made its way in there) in the array with this:

```
array = new LinkedList<>();
```

First, change your field to use eager initialization instead, so you're not overwriting your field on every method call.

```
List<ObjectClass> array = new LinkedList<>();
```

Now, for your method.  You don't enter the loop since `array` is always empty.  Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, you should pass the object through, or create a copy of it *n* times.

```
public void fillArray(int times) {

    for(int i = 0;i < times; i++) {
        data++;
        array.add(new ObjectClass(data));
    }

}
```

Lastly, observe that, if the loop *did* work, `data` and `array.size()` would be equivalent (so long as you didn't remove anything).  I'd rethink the purpose/intent of that variable.

Comment: Thanks, I am working on it. !

Answer (score 4):

The reason why nothing is happening is here:

```
for(int i = 0;i < array.size();i++)
```

The line before, you just created the `array` so it's still empty - therefore, the body of the loop isn't executed at all.

Comment: Ahhhr, yes, yes, did not notice that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Declare the  **`List<ObjectClass> array`** as `static`, it will do what you are trying to achieve by creating a `Class variable` not at **Object Level**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `array` (which is not actually an array by the way - it's mis-named) initially has size 0, so the method does nothing.

You have forgotten to consider how many numbers you want to "fill" the data structure with.